# Why my header in the Pandas dataframe is not aligned with the other headers after under going a groupby().sum() operation?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have cleaned the excel data using pandas and then i wanted to create a new table in mysql database using the headers but as the headers are not aligned it is taking one and not the others...

```
import pandas as pd

if __name__ == "__main__":

    df1 = pd.read_excel(r"C:\Users\Dev\Downloads\receipt vouchers.xls", header=5, index_col=None)
    pd.set_option('display.max_rows', None)  # Show all rows
    pd.set_option('display.max_columns', None)  # Show all columns
    pd.set_option('display.width', None)
    df1 = df1.drop(0)
    df1 = df1.drop(['Date','Vch Type','Vch No.','Debit'],axis=1)
    df1 = df1.sort_values(by='Particulars')
    df1 = df1.reset_index(drop=True)

    df1 = df1.groupby('Particulars').sum()
    print(df1)
```

Output:
[Screenshot of the Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GXioz.png)

Comment: Use `as_index=False`